# Associated model conditions being ignored

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have 2 models: Option and Modifier with such Option belongsTo Modifier relation:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
'Modifier' => array(
    'className' => 'Modifier',
    'foreignKey' => 'modifier_id',
    'conditions' => array('Modifier.type' => '3'),
    'fields' => 'Modifier.name',
    'order' => 'Modifier.name ASC'
)
);
```

In OptionsController I try to get list of Modifiers:

```
$modifiers = $this->Option->Modifier->find('list');
```

And CakePHP generates SQL without conditions, so I get full list of Modifiers. Why CakePHP 2.4.4 ignores conditions, defined in model belongsTo relation? It also ignores fields and order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the right behavior

when you write:

```
$modifiers = $this->Option->Modifier->find('list');
```

you are just accessing Modifier model and not all modifiers related to Option.

to achieve what you want you have to do this:

```
$modifiers = $this->Option->Modifier->find(
    'list', 
    array('conditions' => array('Modifier.type' => '3')
)
```

you can also create your own find type (see [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#creating-custom-find-types))

```
class Modifier extends AppModel {
    public $findMethods = array('type3' =>  true);

    protected function _findType3($state, $query, $results = array()) {
        if ($state === 'before') {
            $query['conditions']['Modifier.type'] = 3;
            return $query;
        }
        return $results;
    }
}
```

and in your controller do this

```
$modifiers = $this->Option->Modifier->find('type3');
```

Comment: I know about find arguments) Why CakePHP ignores relation settings? They look useless. In what case CakePHP starts to use conditions, fields and order settings, defined strictly in model?